# Access to ancestors enums

Tags: java, inheritance, enums, encapsulation

I have a class A which looks like this:

```
public abstract class A {

    protected enum Identifier{
        HELLO,WORLD
    }

    private String identifier;

    public void setIdentifier(Identifier identifier){
        this.identifier=identifier.toString();
    }

    public String getIdentifier(){
        return identifier;
    }
}
```

Now the class hierarchy is this:

```
B extends A
C extends A
D extends B
E extends D

or A->B->D->E and A->C
```

Now if I want to use the setter of `Identifier enum` of `A` in `E` how do I go about it. And also I need to use the getter of the same `enum` in class `C`. Do I need to create a separate method in each of the sub classes to access the ancestor?

Comment: The methods are public now, so you should be able to access them.

Comment: Yes but without instantiating a new object I want to inherit it in the child class in a way which doesnt break the encapsulation.

Comment: You can add to `A` class new method which will return instance of inner enum like `getEnumIdentifier(String enumName)`. This way you will get something like `instance.setIdentifier(instance.getEnumIdentifier("nameOfEnum"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach which I took was:

```
public abstract class A {

    protected enum Identifier{
        HELLO,WORLD
    }

    protected Identifier identifier;
}
```

In the child class `E` I am saying `identifier = Identifier.HELLO;`. I dont know if this is the best approach but even the class `C` can get the same value of the `enum` if its part of the same instance. This approach seems to be a bit obfuscate as it is not very clear immediately that where the `identifier` is inherited from. Any better approach?

Answer (score -1):

Being your code as it is now, you may invoke both the getter and the setter on any sublcass-of-A object, except for one detail: The `Identifier` enum should be also *public*, in order to be accessed by any client class.

Public and protected members are automatically inherited by subclasses. Among them, protected members are accessible from subclasses only. And public members are accessible from any client class.

Comment: I am not sharing this class with any client. `"Public and protected members are automatically inherited by subclasses. Among them, protected members are accessible from subclasses only. And public members are accessible from any client class."` Why are you explaining concepts of inheritance, I believe I asked something else.

Comment: Excuse me, my friend, but you asked `"Now if I want to use the setter of Identifier enum of A in E how do I go about it. "`, and I reply: `"**You may invoke the setter on any object which is subclass of A**"`.